# Can I push notifications in OpenFin after my app has been closed? / How to make my OpenFin app run in background?

Tags: openfin

Can I push notifications in OpenFin after my app has been closed? / How to make my OpenFin app run in background? I have tried and researched a lot, but cannot find an answer for the same. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, If app is closed then you can not push notifications. You can run application in background however you can make the app minimized by code  and push the notification then.. If it solves your purpose.